# how to add JSON data from php to variable in jQuery for use with jQuery image cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, arrays, getjson, jquery-cycle

I am using jQuery .getJSON to push data to objects (I hope I am getting the terminology correct) for use with jQuery Cycle plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ from Malsup. Having difficulty with substituting the image data from a php file into the $banner variable, which is hardcoded in the examples I have seen.

here is the php:

```
mysql_select_db($database_cms_test, $cms_test);

$return_arr = array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pyr_ref WHERE promo_image != '' ORDER BY RAND()"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['promo_image'] = $row['promo_image'];
    $row_array['performer'] = $row['performer_name'];
    $row_array['mp3'] = $row['file_name'];
    $row_array['title'] = $row['song_name'];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

here is the javascript:

```
var image = [];
var caption = [];
var mp3 = [];
var title = [];
var numberOfImages = 0;

var $banner = [];

$.getJSON("promo_fetch1.7.php",function(data){ 
    $.each(data,function(index,obj){
        image.push(obj.promo_image);
        caption.push(obj.performer);
        mp3.push(obj.mp3)   ;
        title.push(obj.title);
    });

//need help around here to get the 4 objects into the $banner array variable

    numberOfImages = title.length;
});

$banner[$i].title = ($banner[$i].title === '')? '':'•' +           $banner[$i].title;

...
```

How do I get the 4 objects (image, caption, mp3, title) into an array equivalent to the Malsup example:

```
var $banner = [{
    "image": "images/image1.png",
    "caption": "Showcase1",
    "link": "#",
    "title": "Song Title1"},
{
    "image": "images/image1.png",
    "caption": "Showcase1",
    "link": "#",
    "title": "Song Title1"},
{
    "image": "images/image1.png",
    "caption": "Showcase1",
    "link": "#",
    "title": "Song Title1"}];
```

Thanks so much for your assistance!

Comment: need to parse your data into html and insert into the DOM. Also might want to consider using the more robust and newer Cycle2

Comment: is there a way to do that "parse your data into html and insert into the DOM" within the js file? a bit confused about how to implement your suggestion